# Include function arguments in stack trace when raising error

Tags: elixir

In Erlang, when raising an error I can include the arguments to the current function by passing a second argument to `error`:

```erlang
-module(foo).

-export([foo/2]).

foo(A, B) ->
    error(something_went_wrong, [A, B]).
```

This means that the arguments will be visible in the stack trace, which can make debugging easier:

```
> foo:foo(1, 2).
foo:foo(1, 2).
** exception error: something_went_wrong
     in function  foo:foo/2
        called as foo:foo(1,2)
```

In both Erlang and Elixir, this happens automatically on function clause errors:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def foo(a, b) when false do
    :ok
  end
end
```

```
> Foo.foo(1, 2)
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Foo.foo/2    
    
    The following arguments were given to Foo.foo/2:
    
        # 1
        1
    
        # 2
        2
    
    foo.ex:2: Foo.foo/2
```

Is there a way to include function arguments for explicitly raised exceptions in Elixir, other than calling `:erlang.error` directly? I looked at [the documentation for `Kernel.raise`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#raise/2) and didn't find anything suitable.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like a cop-out, but I believe the preferred way of doing this is to use `inspect/2` on variables in your message, e.g.

```
raise ArgumentError, 
    message: "There was a problem with the inputs: #{inspect(a)} #{inspect(b)}"

# Yields:    
# ** (ArgumentError) There was a problem with the inputs: "foo" "bar"
```

The examples in the [Elixir defexception docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defexception/1) more or less do the same, just attached to a custom exception module, something like:

```
defmodule ABError do
  defexception [:message]
end

a = "foo"
b = "bar"

raise ABError,
  message: "There was a problem with the inputs: #{inspect(a)} #{inspect(b)}"

# Yields:
# ** (ABError) There was a problem with the inputs: "foo" "bar"
```

With your background in Erlang, you might be able to make more sense of how all this threads its way back through the [Exception module](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Exception.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is no generic way of doing that because the exception in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) is just a struct. On the other hand, that gives you the flexibility that is, for instance, used in the aforementioned `FunctionClauseError`, [that is defined as](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11.2/lib/elixir/lib/exception.ex#L1090)

```
defexception [:module, :function, :arity, :kind, :args, :clauses]
```

So when the compiler raises it, `message` is constructed to include [arguments](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.11.2/lib/elixir/lib/exception.ex#L1110) passed through with the original error.

---

To achieve the same, one usually defines the custom exception with [`Kernel.defexception/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#defexception/1), accepting arguments and implementing both `message/1` and [`blame/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Exception.html#c:blame/2) callbacks from `Exception` behaviour. A good example would be the source of `FunctionClauseError` implementation, I linked above.